Complete list of functions known to satisfy the Siegel-Walfisz assumption
When I was reading Yitang Zhang's paper "Bounded Gaps between Primes" Text, on Page 1145, it is stated that "It should be remarked, by the Siegel-Walfisz theorem, that for all the
choices of $\beta$ above, the Siegel-Walfisz assumption in (A2) holds." But this is not proved in the paper.
Can anyone kindly provide a proof (or proof sketch) of the above statement? Also, it would be nice to list all functions (or function classes) known to satisfy the Siegel-Walfisz assumption and their respective methods of proofs.
Thanks.
